# Having flash running on server controlled by a canvas on client

Tags: javascript, flash, canvas, server

I know it sounds weird but I would like to know if anybody knows if it could be possible to have a Flash application running in a sandbox on the server and to have an html canvas on the client which reproduces the flash content as an image and allows the user to interact with it sending mouse interaction to the server hosted flash.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know FMIS at all, but fast reading from [Adobe's page](http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-media-server-professional/features.html), I would say that HLS + [MSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) is your best bet to draw flash from server on a canvas, for the interaction part however, I don't have enough courage to search the whole docs to find it out, but I guess it should be doable yes... (that would mean no need for flash plugin... sounds good to me)

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna give a look immediatly. You got exactly the point, this would allow to have flash apps served without the need of the plugin. The idea came to me cause I need to refactor a quite complex flash app in js using easeljs canvas and kilos of html/css.